# "From" address while using perl script to send a mail?

Tags: perl

What I'm trying to understand here is what should we put in the `from` option in this Sendmail snippet. If I'm running the script from my local windows machine, what can i do to send the mail?

```
use Mail::Sendmail;

sendmail(
From    => 'sender@somewhereelse.com',
To      => 'recipient@somewhere.com',
Subject => 'some subject',
Message => "body of the message",
);
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. You set the 'from' header to whoever you want the email to come from.

Comment: I think it is my fault, Sorry for my poor English. What i was trying to ask is that when we used to run scripts on Unix servers we just gave the `To` option and we used to receive mails from the server. I never used to give `From` option anywhere actually. So is it possible to send mails from my local desktop to my gmail address.?

Answer (score 1):

Under the assumption that you're using [`SMTP`](http://search.cpan.org/~mivkovic/Mail-Sendmail-0.79/Sendmail.pm#CONFIGURATION) to send mail,

```
unshift @{$Mail::Sendmail::mailcfg{'smtp'}} , 'my.mail.server';
```

you can put in `from` field anything what would you put in Thunderbird/Outlook client.